# Python PIL Paste

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to paste a bunch of images together with PIL. For some reason, when I run the line `blank.paste(img,(i*128,j*128))` I get the following error: `ValueError: cannot determine region size; use 4-item box`

I tried messing with it and using a tuple with 4 elements like it said (ex. (128,128,128,128)) but it gives me this error: `SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple`

Each image is 128x and has a naming style of "x_y.png" where x and y are from 0 to 39. My code is below.

```
from PIL import Image

loc = 'top right/'
blank = Image.new("RGB", (6000,6000), "white")

for x in range(40):
    for y in reversed(range(40)):
        file = str(x)+'_'+str(y)+'.png'
        img = open(loc+file)
        blank.paste(img,(x*128,y*128))

blank.save('top right.png')
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not loading the image correctly. The built-in function [open](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) just opens a new file descriptor. To load an image with PIL, use `Image.open` instead:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("bride.jpg") # open the file and "load" the image in one statement
```

If you have a reason to use the built-in open, then do something like this:

```
fin = open("bride.jpg") # open the file
img = Image.open(fin) # "load" the image from the opened file
```

With PIL, "loading" an image means reading the image header. PIL is lazy, so it doesn't load the actual image data until it needs to.

Also, consider using [os.path.join](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) instead of string concatenation.

Comment: That worked, thanks. I knew it was going to be something stupid like that.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me, I'm using Odoo v9 and I have pillow 4.0.

I did it steps in my server with ubuntu:

```
# pip uninstall pillow
# pip install Pillow==3.4.2
# /etc/init.d/odoo restart
```

Answer (score 2):

For me the methods above didn't work.

After checking *image.py* I found that `image.paste(color)` needs one more argument like `image.paste(color, mask=original)`. It worked well for me by changing it to this:

```
image.paste(color, box=(0, 0) + original.size)
```